# how to add the root tag in an xml file with xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to add a root tag in an xml document using xsl, but I have done several examples and could not.

```
   <log4j:event logger="grails.app.controllers.org.example.UserController"      timestamp="1376174488361" level="INFO" thread="http-bio-8888-exec-1">
        <log4j:message><![CDATA[ Realizando login]]></log4j:message>
   </log4j:event>

   <log4j:event logger="grails.app.controllers.org.example.UserController" timestamp="1376174488361" level="ERROR" thread="http-bio-8888-exec-1">
        <log4j:message><![CDATA[Olá sou uma mensagem de erro]]></log4j:message>
   </log4j:event>
```

Comment: What is it that you are showing us? Where is your XSL?

Comment: If your snippet is your actual input file, then it is invalid -- XML *needs* a root element to be valid. Thus, your average XSLT processor cannot work with this inout.

Comment: I want to know how if is possible create a root for this xml document using xslt.

Comment: See this thread for a possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517347/how-to-add-the-root-tag-in-an-xml-file-with-xsl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a root using xslt for xml document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518084/create-a-root-using-xslt-for-xml-document)